# How i can create dynaminc ordered list items with pure css

Tags: css

I wants to make the ordered list like mentioned below image.

So how i can make this ordered list with pure CSS.....

As i will increase the list item boxes numbers should dynamically increase with increased list item boxes.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean: Can I add more list item boxes with CSS? Or can I increase the number in the corner with CSS, so when I have 11 boxes they go from 1 to 11?

Comment: you mean you want to use a counter to automatically increment the numbers of your list? like with a css counter?

Comment: yup exactly when i will increase the number of list item boxes so the numbers should automatically increase as mentioned above image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Shailender Arora Now you can used Counter properties and do this with pure css

As like this

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>


</ul>
```

**Css**

```
li {
float:left;
background:#e6e6e6;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:10px;
}

li {
counter-increment:shail;
}

li:after {
  content:counter(shail);
}
```

**Live demo** http://tinkerbin.com/xq0uATYn

Answer (score 5):

try this example fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/AENt7/

Relevant CSS code

```
ul {
  counter-reset: item;
  height : auto;
  overflow : hidden;
}

li {
  float : left;
  width : 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background : #d8d8d8;
  counter-increment: item   
}

ul li:nth-child(5n + 1) {
  clear : left;
}

li:before {
  content : counter(item);
}
```

the number on each block will be automatically inserted through the counter defined for `<ul>` element and incremented in every `<li>`. It is inserted as content of `before` pseudoelement.

A note on compatibility:  `nth-child` pseudoclass requires at least IE9, `before` requires at least IE8.

A basic float clearing is applied to `<ul>` with `overflow: hidden` and `height: auto`.

Hope this helps

Comment: the nice part of using css counters is the automatic update also when you dinamycally insert an element via javascript in the middle of your list. All numbers will be updated

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Pallazzo had a good idea. But, since PHP isn't available to everybody, here's a pure JavaScript solution.

```
document.write("<ol>");
var i;
var endLimit = 11; //you can make this anything that makes you happy

for (i = 1; i <= endLimit; i++) {
       document.write('<li>' + i + '</li>');
}

document.write("</ol>");
```